# Cypress how to check if div contains one of two Strings?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am starting my journey with Cypess and I have met the small problem. I need to check if div element has text which is one of two.

```
 getText(text1, text2) {
    cy.get([data-cy=default-login-failed-label]).should('have.any.text', (text1, text2))
  }
```

Could someone help me please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `to.be.oneOf` assertion for this.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=default-login-failed-label]')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    expect(text).to.be.oneOf([text1, text2])
  })
```

Comment: this approach works, thank you! I will use it! 
But I still don't know why my approach with passing texts in parameters doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

You code works for me:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=default-login-failed-label]')
  .should('have.any.text', ('one', 'two'))     // passes
```

Tested with

```html
<div data-cy="default-login-failed-label">two</div>
```

Also works if the text is "one".

The only thing I can see wrong in your question is the selector quotes are missing, but I presume that's a typo.